# Break up of Amount - SQL

Tags: sql

I need to break an amount (Number) into components, for instance, an amount of 58963 is to be broken into 50000, 8000, 900, 60 and 3, how do I achieve this in sql using a function, any idea?

Regards,

Irfan

Comment: You should do that in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: It's probably homework, so that might not be an option.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: (read this in professor farnsworth's voice:) I'm afraid you have to use...MATH!

Comment: @MSalters LOL :-)

Comment: For Postgres: `select x::int * 10 ^ (n-1) from regexp_split_to_table(reverse(58963::text), '') with ordinality as t(x,n) `

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DECLARE @amount INT = 58963
DECLARE @temp INT
DECLARE @i INT = 0

DECLARE @tempStore TABLE(val int)

WHILE(@amount>0)
BEGIN
    SET @temp = @amount % 10;
    SET @amount = @amount /10;
    INSERT INTO @tempStore VALUES(@temp * POWER(10, @i))
    SET @i = @i+1;
END

SELECT * FROM @tempStore ORDER BY val DESC
```

You can use `bigint` instead of `int` if the value does not fit in integer range.

If you want to get the comma separated output try

```
DECLARE @amount BIGINT = 589625
DECLARE @temp BIGINT
DECLARE @i INT = 0

DECLARE @tempStore TABLE(val BIGINT)

WHILE(@amount>0)
BEGIN
    SET @temp = @amount % 10;
    SET @amount = @amount /10;
    INSERT INTO @tempStore VALUES(@temp * POWER(10, @i))
    SET @i = @i+1;
END

DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(MAX)= ''
select @tmp = @tmp + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), val ) + ', ' from @tempStore ORDER BY val DESC

select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))
```

If you want to implement this with a database way rather than a general programming logic (Don't want the WHILE loop) then you can try

```
DECLARE @amount AS INT = 58963;
;WITH cte
      AS ( SELECT  1 AS n, @amount AS m, 1 as p, 1 as r
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  (cte.m%10), (cte.m / 10), (cte.p*10), ((cte.m%10) * (cte.p*10))/10
           FROM cte
           WHERE cte.m > 0
         )

SELECT cte.r --,*
FROM    cte WHERE (cte.n*cte.p)/10 > 0
--ORDER BY cte.r DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server

```
DECLARE @num INT = 58963;

with decList as
(
  select 10 AS decNum
  union all
  select decNum  * 10 AS dt
  from decList
  where decNum  <= @num
)
select CASE WHEN decNum > 10 
            THEN ((@num % decNum) / (decNum / 10)) * (decNum / 10)
            ELSE @num % decNum
       END
from decList
```

Comment: This works , but we have to change for every change in number of digits

Comment: true, I'll try to update

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number.

```
DECLARE @amount AS INT = 58963;

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS n
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   cte.n * 10
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    cte.n < @amount / 10
             )
    SELECT  ( ( @amount % ( cte.n * 10 ) ) / cte.n ) * cte.n
    FROM    cte;
```

Comment: You can use `WHERE    cte.n < @amount / 10` instead of `WHERE    cte.n * 10 < @amount` to generate power of 10. It will ensure you, for an integer n, the condition will not overflow.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Good point.